# Pandas groupby apply customized function to each group

Tags: python, pandas, sum, pandas-groupby

I have a table with multiple columns. For one of the columns **AC**, I need to replace it with **Result AC** as shown in the table below

[image]

The function has a pseudo code as below:

```
For each unique address:
If 
# of unique(AC) < Value in column B AND 
len(Top 1 (unique(AC))) != len(Top 2 (unique(AC))):
return mode(air_conditioning) 

Else
For each unique(AC), calculate sum(area)
If Top 1 (sum(area)) > Top 2 (SUM(area)):
return air_conditioning which has Top 1 (SUM(building_area))

Else
For each unique(AC), SUM(value)
return air_conditioning with Top 1 (SUM(value))
```

Comment: Is [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66541891/198633) sufficiently similar?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Groupby, transfrom sum should do

```
df['col2']=df.groupby('col1')['col2'].transform('sum')
```